# React native Image in two scrollView not showing

Tags: image, react-native, flexbox, scrollview

I started react-native and I am having a hard time finding how I can load a picture from an **uri** and show it into two scrollView (seems I need that, one for vertical and one for horizontal scrolls). I could make it works for a local file, but as soon as I get it from internet, the picture never show up except if I give a specific size.

```
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 0, alignContent: "stretch" }}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true} contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 0, alignContent: "stretch" }}>
        <Image
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}
          resizeMode='cover'
          source={{ uri: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/15/11/15/wintry-2068298_960_720.jpg' }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

The same code without the scrollViews shows the image perfectly but with them the image never shows. I tried, the `alignSelf:'stretch'`, or to set `top/bottom/right/left` to `0` and also `width:'100%'` and `height:'100%'` for the image nothing giving the expected result which is **take all the space possible showing the image and be able to scroll inside it horizontally and vertically**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer :

```
var myUri = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/15/11/15/wintry-2068298_960_720.jpg';
var mode = 'cover'
Image.getSize(myUri, (width, height) => { this.setState({ width, height }) });
return (
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 0 }}>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 0 }}>
      <Image
        style={{ width: width, height: height }}
        resizeMode={mode}
        source={{ uri: myUri }}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  </ScrollView>
);
```